# Uploading images to AWS S3 bucket - specifying file path for randomly generated file names

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, puppeteer

I'm working on an automated testing project using PuppeteerJS in headless Chrome and trying to integrate existing screenshot functionality with AWS-SDK to upload images to an AWS S3 bucket on test failure.

The problem i'm having is the sub directories in a screenshots folder and the image file names are generated randomly in another file based on the current date and test environment, and run every time a test runs. The format of the generated directories/files is "screenshots/year/month/day/randomname.png".

The next step in the test is after the screenshots are generated, the folder containing the newly created images should be uploaded to AWS, and I've tried to achieve this using a glob to get every subdirectory and file with a png extension, like `"screenshots/**/**/**/*.png"`, but i get a "no such file or directory" error". The folders/file names will be different everytime the tests run.

I've just started using AWS and I haven't been able to find a specific answer to my problem while researching.

```
import { PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import { s3Client } from "../libs/s3Client.js"; 
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

const file = "../../screenshots/**/**/**/*.png"; 

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);

// Set the parameters
export const uploadParams = {
  Bucket: "bucket-name",
  Key: path.basename(file),
  // Add the required 'Body' parameter
  Body: fileStream,
};

// Upload file to specified bucket.
export const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(uploadParams));
    console.log("Success", data);
    return data; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
run();
```

Comment: So is the problem that you don't know what the local filename is, or that you don't know how to add a folder/path to the file in S3? I'm confused as to what the actual issue is. Can you please edit your question to demonstrate the intended result, and the current result?

Comment: Hi Mark, i've amended my question. It's that i won't know the filename until the test runs and fails, and the folder with images of the failure are generated. I'm therefore unable to include a file path to the images in the aws-sdk upload file. I've tried to use a glob pattern to get everything with a png extension, but that didn't work

Comment: @jarmod I agree, but the code in the question is NodeJS, not Python.

Comment: Determine the actual names of the files, then upload then one by one. Perhaps use the `fs` package ([example](https://www.webmound.com/nodejs-get-files-in-directories-recursively/)).

Comment: Thanks Jarmod, using readdir() did what i wanted and grabs the file path from the folder

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out with the help of Jarmod. I needed to use the nodeJS:fs module to get the file paths recursively and returns a string which can be passed into the AWS fileStream variable for it to be uploaded to AWS. Jarmod shared the webmound article and i found the coder rocket fuel article hepful also.

https://www.webmound.com/nodejs-get-files-in-directories-recursively/

https://coderrocketfuel.com/article/recursively-list-all-the-files-in-a-directory-using-node-js